# Помогите запустить проект на maven

Tags: java, maven

Здравствуйте. Хочу запустить проект который парсит сайт с помощью http://ru.selenide.org. Вот мой pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.selenide.examples</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.3</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-archetype-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>org.selenide.examples.NBU</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Собираю с помощью команды mvn clean package. Потом захожу в папку target и запускаю вот так: java -jar my-app-1.0.jar. В консоле вижу ошибку no main manifest attribute, in my-app-1.0.jar. Уже третий день питаюсь это исправить но не получаэтся. Помгите пожалуйста. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Либо запускайте с явным указанием класса содержащего статический метод `main`:

```
java -cp my-app-1.0.jar org.selenide.examples.NBU
```

Либо в pom.xml

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>org.selenide.examples.NBU</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: А что делать если такая теперь ошибка Could not find or load main class org.selenide.exemples.NBU? Вставил Ваш buil и запускаю ava -cp my-app-1.0.jar org.selenide.examples.NBU

Comment: Значит либо в jar-файле нет такого класса, либо у этого класса нет метода `main`.